# .NET Abstract Class Inheritance and Generics

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, inheritance, abstract-class

Here's the layout of classes:

```
Public MustInherit Class AbstractBase
    Public MustOverride Function GetTest() As String

    Public Sub PrintTest()
        System.Console.WriteLine(Me.GetTest())
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestA
    Inherits AbstractBase

    Public Overrides Function GetTest() As String
        Return "Hello from A"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TestB
    Inherits AbstractBase

    Public Overrides Function GetTest() As String
        Return "Hello from B"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TestUser(Of T As AbstractBase)

    Public Sub Print()
        Dim x As AbstractBase = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

        x.PrintTest()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TestUserA
    Inherits TestUser(Of TestA)

''' Custom TestUserA code

End Class

Public Class TestUserB
   Inherits TestUser(of TestB)

''' Custom TestUserB Stuff

End Class
```

This is the problem area:

```
Dim a As TestUser(Of AbstractBase) = New TestUserA()
```

The compiler says they `TestUserA` can't be cast to `TestUser(Of AbstractBase)`. I'm not sure why though because `TestUserA` inherites from `TestUser(Of TestA)` and `TestA` inherits from `AbstractBase`. To me this inheritence structure looks correct so I'm not sure why this wouldn't work?

The idea is that `AbstractBase` implements some general functionality I need. `TestUserA` and `TestUserB` need `TestA` and `TestB` to do there processing. But I also need to be able to create separate instances of `TestA` and `TestB` without instantiating `TestUserA` or `TestUserB`.

So that I could do:

```
Dim a As TestUser(Of AbstractBase) = New TestUserA()
a.Print()

Dim aTest As New TestA()
Dim x = aTest.GetTest()

Public Function DoThings() As TestUser(Of AbstractBase)
    Dim a As TestUser(Of AbstractBase) = New TestUserA()

    return a
End Function
```

Comment: Can somebody please explain why this inheritance structure doesn't work? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a base class for your `TestUser(Of AbstractBase)` to inherit from:

```
Public MustInherit Class TestUser
   Public Sub Print()
      Dim x As AbstractBase = CreateTest()
      x.PrintTest()
   End Sub

   Protected MustOverride Function CreateTest() As AbstractBase 'IMO the type name should really be AbstractTest not AbstractBase 

End Class
```

Then put the genrics-based factory implemenetation into `TestUser(Of AbstractBase)`:

```
Public Class TestUser(Of T As AbstractBase)
   Inherits TestUser

   Protected Overrides Function CreateTest() As AbstractBase
      Return Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()
   End Function

End Class
```

Your TestUserA and TestUserB are unchanged.

Now your Main code looks like this:

```
Sub Main()


  Dim a As TestUser = New TestUserA()
  a.Print()

  Dim aTest As New TestA()
  Dim x = aTest.GetTest()

End Sub

Public Function DoThings() As TestUser

  Dim a As TestUser = New TestUserA()
  Return a

End Function
```

Good luck!

Comment: This came as close to what I was trying to achieve. Most of the other answers work for the specific situation. But this solution fits into a much larger more complex ASP.NET app. Although it looks more complex this solution provides the simplest overall design in my opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dim` without the `As`, like this:

```
Dim a = New TestUserA()
a.DoOtherStuff()
```

Note: You will need to use `Option Strict Off` for the above to work. You can also use `Option Infer On` to help with the syntax above.

Answer (score 0):

Your TestUser class should look like this:

```
Public Class TestUser

    Public Sub Print(x As AbstractBase)
        x.PrintTest()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then you can print it like this:

```
    Dim a As AbstractBase = New TestA()
    Dim usr As New TestUser
    usr.Print(a)
```